# WP Images not showing up with HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, image, http, https, http-status-code-404

Im facing a strange problem with SSL, in fact all my images didn't showing up on SSL, this is an example :

HTTP : http://www.electronique-mixte.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/numidea-logo-electronique-mixte.png

HTTPS : https://www.electronique-mixte.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/numidea-logo-electronique-mixte.png

For the same picture, the HTTP is working, but the HTTPS is not !

Any idea ?

**Website :**

[image: HTTPS no picture is showing up]

**HTTPS picture 404 error:**

[image]

**HTTP working fine:**

[image]

**Another browser (Edge):**

[image]
PS : i'm using incognito tab, (avoid cache)

Comment: Actually it works for me in both cases. To be sure try accessing them via different browser / device or via curl.

Comment: is a very strange bug, can you please try this with the both cases ; https://www.electronique-mixte.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Commande-dun-moteur-%C3%A0-CC-avec-une-manette-visuelle_-manette-150x150.png

Comment: I think you need to check the
[link](https://managewp.com/blog/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings)
[link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/replacing-image-links/)

Comment: @Jagirbahesh thank you for your answer if fact is not a mixed content problem, the test show the : Mixed Content - Pass:  You have no mixed content.  and i already forced HTTPS content ! and i already updated URLS !

Comment: they both work for me ... check incognito? Or another browser? Can you show us your htaccess?

Comment: @Ovidash i'm working with two laptops, on incognito, same problem, can you please check https://www.electronique-mixte.fr/ and see if images are showing up ?

Comment: can you please reselect image from admin side?

Comment: @Jagirbahesh how can i do it ? for example the logo ?

Comment: yes, go to wp-admin side and remove logo --> save
and reselected logo and save.
I hope its work for you.

Comment: @Jagirbahesh same problem :/

Comment: @AITMANSOURMohamed if I access the images directly they work, if I access the url of the website, the images do not work. Hence my request to show us the **htaccess** file contents, please.

Comment: I am sure there is caching issue.
please disable cache with `define('WP_CACHE', false);`
please add this code in the wp-config.php file and then clear your cache and then check.

Comment: @Ovidash i found the solution, it was on htaccess like you said, in fact there was RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http  [L,R=301] i just changed it to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https  [L,R=301]
 and now everything is working properly, thank you all !

Comment: glad I could help @AITMANSOURMohamed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution :

1. Update db, and change http to HTTPS (i used Better [Search Replace Plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/))
2. Remove cache
3. Update htaccess change all http urls to HTTPS
4. force using SSL (i used [Really Simple SSL](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin)

Thank you for your comments !

Comment: I have already given this ans in my 1st reply [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794152/wp-images-not-showing-up-with-https#comment88594544_50794152) please check 1st reply in 2 link.

Comment: Thank you, but they didn't mention that we have to update .htaccess, i used there plugins, and they helped me, but the problem still persist until i'hve updated .htaccess

Comment: This method does not work in both the case of http and https

Answer (score 6):

**Add meta tag in your theme header :**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Answer (score 3):

Because no one else mentioned this: since this is in WordPress (based on the URL structure), make sure your "Site Address" and "WordPress Address" include "https" in the URL:

[image: Be sure to include "https" in your WordPress settings for the "WordPress Address" and "Site Address", otherwise your theme files may try and serve insecure content, thus preventing most browsers from rendering it properly.]

Located in Settings > General.

Because WordPress uses these fields to generate image URLs, it's important to include the "https" here, even if you're otherwise redirecting to HTTPS (such as through Apache or Nginx).

Answer (score 1):

Writing the following code in wp-config.php file will solve the issue.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) && "https" == $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"] ) {
$_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on";
}
```

Hope that will work for you.